# how to define a KeyboardView's xml file

Tags: android

I want to design a custom keyboard matching my app. So,I found KeyboardView in android developer which maybe I could use.But a problem appeared that be raised above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Android samples.  There's a KeyboardView sample included.  It contains sample XML files as well:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/qwerty.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/symbols.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/symbols_shift.html

This should get you started.